# How to draw SVG with external CSS on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: css, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to draw the SVG using external CSS file on a canvas.

In the following sample codes, it has the first polygon (triangle) using SVG, second one with canvas drawn from SVG and third one an image converted from the canvas.   The `<polygon>` SVG tag is using the ploygon CSS from the external common.css file

svgtest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
        <link href="common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="svg-container">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="500" height="210">
         <defs>
         </defs>
            <g>
               <rect x="78" y="78" width="694" height="284" style="stroke-width: 0px; fill: #ffffff; fill-opacity: 1;"></rect>
            <svg width="500" height="210" >
              <polygon class="ploygon" points="200,10 250,190 160,210" />
            </svg>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="210"></canvas>
      <div id="png-container"></div>
      <script>
         var svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
         svgElement.onload = function() {
             var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
             var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });

             var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
             var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
             var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
             var img = new Image();
             var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
             img.src = url;
             img.onload = function () {
                 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                 var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                 document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
                 DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
             };
         }
         var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas");

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

common.css:

```
 .ploygon {
    fill:lime;
 }
```

When I put the CSS `<link>` in the `<head>` as shown above, the 1st SVG triangle can use the .ploygon CSS and filled with lime color, the 2nd and 3rd triangle are filled with black.

[image]

I have read that the CSS link tag can be put inside the SVG.  When I do the following:

```
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="850" height="440">
         <defs>
            <link href="common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>   
         </defs>
        <g>
           <rect x="78" y="78" width="694" height="284" style="stroke-width: 0px; fill: #ffffff; fill-opacity: 1;"></rect>
        <svg height="210" width="500">
          <polygon class="ploygon" points="200,10 250,190 160,210" />
        </svg>
        </g>
     </svg>
```

All 3 triangles do not use the CSS and filled with black:

[image]

If I change to use the inline style inside the `<svg>` like this

```
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="500" height="210">
         <defs>
            <style>
                 .ploygon {
                    fill:lime;
                 }
            </style>
         </defs>
        <g>
           <rect x="78" y="78" width="694" height="284" style="stroke-width: 0px; fill: #ffffff; fill-opacity: 1;"></rect>
        <svg width="500" height="210" >
          <polygon class="ploygon" points="200,10 250,190 160,210" />
        </svg>
        </g>
     </svg>
```

Then all 3 triangles are filled with lime:

[image]

I have tried using import the common.css inside the `<defs>`, but it does not use the css file.    I don't want to put the CSS style inline.    Is there any good solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be reading the CSS file content and insert it as a style node into your SVG:

```js
// Create style element and insert the rules in it
let style = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "style");
style.textContent = getCssStringFromFile('common.css');
svgElement.insertBefore(style, svgElement.firstChild);
```

Here is getCssStringFromFile function:

```js
/**
 * Returns css rules as string from linked css file 
 * @param {string} fileName - The css file name.
 */
function getCssStringFromFile(fileName){
  let cssStyles = "";

  for(let i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];

        if (!styleSheet.href || styleSheet.href.indexOf(fileName) == -1)
           continue;

        let style = null;

        if (styleSheet) {
           if (typeof styleSheet.cssRules !== "undefined")
              style = styleSheet.cssRules;
           else if (typeof styleSheet.rules !== "undefined")
              style = styleSheet.rules;
        }
        for(let item in style) {
           if(typeof style[item].cssText !== "undefined")
              cssStyles += (style[item].cssText);
        }

        break;
  }

  return cssStyles;
}
```

Please see the demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/RecklessPiercingTelephone)

Comment: Mohsen, Thanks for your codes.  It works on Chrome.  Just one minor bug, it should be += in the following line:

cssStyles += (style[item].cssText);


I have different issue now.  It does not work on IE and Edge.